# Find two matching rows and display data from the thirt one (Excel)

Tags: excel, indexing, match, rows, vlookup

So i have Two Sheets.

First sheet contains two columns

BRAND | LEFTOVER

The second sheet consists of two columns also.

BRAND | LEFTOVER (%)

So in case if the BRAND row value in the first Sheet will match the BRAND row value in the second i want to display the matching LEFTOVER (%) row value in the first sheet rows in the column LEFTOVER.

Kind of lost here.

Appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2:

```
.   A   |     B
--------------------
1 BRAND | LEFTOVER %
2   X   |     Y
3       |
```

In Sheet1:

```
.   A   |     B
--------------------
1 BRAND | LEFTOVER
2   X   | =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2)
3       |
```

The VLookup function searches for its first parameter (in this case the value of Sheet1!A2) in the first column of the range denoted by the second parameter (in this case the leftmost column of the range containing columns A and B on Sheet2)

It then returns the value from that same row of the range that is to the right in the columns denoted by the third parameter (1 is the leftmost column where the matched value was).  So in this case we use the number 2 because 1 means column A and 2 is column B (which explains why we used a two column wide range for the second parameter - it needed to encompass the column the result was in)

This isn't the only way to do this, but it is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

As Jerry stated `VLOOKUP` is the simplest way to do this.

HOWEVER if you have multiple/repeat instances (rows) in BRAND, `VLOOKUP` will only return the first record (row) that appears in your data.

If this is the case, you will need to add either a unique identifier column; and/or additional criteria to differentiate between the repeat instances.

As an example column A is used as a unique identifier to differentiate between the 2 'Nike' rows.

```
A       B          C
1     BRAND    LEFTOVER 
2     Nike        50
3     Adidas      25
4     Reebok      30
5     Nike        29
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you can use vlookup to accomplish your goals.

Let me explain it in a bit detail.Suppose you have two sheets as:

```
       A    |     B             |           A   |     B
    ---------------------       |       -------------------
    1 BRAND | LEFTOVER %        |       1 BRAND | LEFTOVER
    2   X   |     Y             |       2   X   |  =Vlookup(A2,Sheet2!A:B,False)
    3       |                   |       3       |
         Sheet2                 |             Sheet1
```

After this you can drag this formula for the entire range. This will automatically make the formula correct for the below cells as well.

Also, if you need to populate any other fields from the Sheet2 then you can also use the vlookup as an array formula like: VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,{1,2,3,4},FALSE)

- Enter this as an array formula using Crtl+Shift+Enter
- Here {1,2,3,4} stands for the columns to be fetched.

If you want to know more about vlookup then read this article: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-excel